# Convert Android project to use Gradle Script Kotlin

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I would like to convert `build.gradle` files in my Android projects from Groovy to Kotlin using [Gradle Script Kotlin](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin). Preferably I'd like all of them in Kotlin, but if there are some limitations then as much as possible.

Lets assume I have just an empty project, freshly created from an Android Studio "New application" template (`minSdkVersion 15`, using AppCompat if that matters). What steps do I need to take for such project to convert it to Gradle Script Kotlin.

I hope this should be a great starting point for me (and everybody else) and I can can handle converting any custom logic I have on my own.

Comment: As described in https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/releases/tag/v1.0.0-M1 , at this time Gradle Script Kotlin does not support external plugins, and thus can't be used to build Android projects.

Comment: Thanks @yole! I know about that, I've seen discussions that you can migrate some parts of build scripts to Kotlin, that's why I said I'd accept answers that convert "as much as possible". So I hope people might share their attempts and hacks.

Answer (score 2):

there's already an `hello-android` example which descibe how to do it.

Check: https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/tree/master/samples/hello-android

Note that:

> It has been tested against Android Studio 2.2 Preview 6 with the latest Kotlin plugin from the EAP 1.1 channel.

Read also: https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/issues/2

Hope it will help